# Create square/triangle/sawtooth and normal sine in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create some sin(2x) 2000HZ, square wave 1000hz, triangle wave 1000 hz, sawtooth 1000 hz. Number of points per each graph should be 62000.

Is this a good start? For some reason y2,y3,y4 are not created..

```
t = 0:0.001:0.62; % Sampling frequency 6.2kHz
y1=sin(2*pi*2000*t);
y2 =square(2*pi*1000*t);
y3= sawtooth(2*pi*1000*t);
y4= sawtooth(2*pi*1000*t,1/2); %triangle
```

Update:

```
t = 0:0.001:0.62; % Sampling frequency 6.2kHz

y1 = sin(2000*t);
y2 = square(1000*t);
y3 = sawtooth(1000*t);
y4= 10 * sawtooth(1000*t ,0.5) + 5;
```

Comment: Are you getting an error that prevents the code from reaching `y2`, `y3`, and `y4`?

Comment: Attempt to execute SCRIPT square as a function:
C:\Users\Bogdan Bagdasar\Documents\MATLAB\square.m

Error in square (line 3)
y2 =square(2*pi*1000*t);

Comment: @bogdanb Your error says that you've got a script called `square.m` in your current path. Try renaming this script to something else that's not a MATLAB function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square and sawtooth functions require the Signal Processing Toolbox.
So you can also create your own function:

```
t = 0:0.1:8*pi;

y1 = sin(t);
y2 = square(t);
y3 = sawtooth(t);
```

**With square.m:**

```
function y = square(x)

inp = sin(x) >= 0;
y(~inp) = -1;
y(inp) = 1;

end
```

**With sawtooth.m**

```
function y = sawtooth(x)

y = ((mod(x,2*pi)/(pi*2))*2)-1;

end
```

**Result:**

[image: subplot]

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I set the frequency for that and number of points? Also how do I make the sawtooth output symmetrical/isosceles  triangles?

Comment: I don't understand you question, don't change your previous code, keep the same sample rate and the same fundamental frequency and you're done.

Comment: Check my update on my original post above. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

`square` and `sawtooth` functions require the `Signal Processing Toolbox`.

The two first lines generate a sinusoidal signal correctly.

Comment: can these be generated without the toolbox?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but you have to check if you have the toolbox installed. Otherwise you can create your own functions to generate this signals.